# Numeric limits - is there a limit when multiplying very large constants?

Tags: c++

Is there an explicitly defined limit on the size of numbers a compiler can handle when multiplying out constants?

```
#define val1 1000000000000000
#define val2 <some really really big number>

std::cerr << val1 * val2 << std::endl;
```

Would this generate an error due to numeric limits in c++ given a sufficiently large value for val2?  Where/how is that limit defined if so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be treat as an integer and so the maximum integer (defined in [limits.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h)) would apply

If you want a large number use 1000.......0000L to define it as a long.

Comment: True if `val2` is also an `int` expression. And a `long` may or may not be bigger than an `int`, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The limits are defined in the [`numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/) class.

Answer (score 2):

There's an implementation dependent maximum, but if you overflow in
constant arithmetic, the implementation is required to issue a
diagnostic (error message).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will use the most suitable size depending on the location of your constant. If it is too big you'll receive an compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Each type (int, long, float, double) has a machine dependent max value.

Float and double values that conform to the IEEE standard will give you a NaN or Infinity if they can't handle the value.